# MySQL Workbench: ROUND() greyed out in window function

Tags: mysql, database

I'm writing a window function to view the averagerating of a certain titleType together with the rating of each movie. The query was working without any rounding functions, but to improve the readability I wanted to round the 2 averages. I wrapped the AVG() function with a ROUND() function, but the ROUND greyed out and the accompanying OVER gets red underlined because it shouldn't occur at that position.

```
SELECT 
ratings.tconst, titles.titleType, 
titles.primaryTitle, 
ratings.averageRating AS rating,
ratings.numVotes,
ROUND(AVG(ratings.averageRating)) OVER (PARTITION BY titleType) averageRating, 
CAST(AVG(ratings.numVotes) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) OVER (PARTITION BY titleType) averageNumberOfVotes 
FROM titleRatings ratings
INNER JOIN titleBasics titles
ON ratings.tconst = titles.tconst;
```

I also tried rounding the average by casting it to a decimal, but it gives the same error (but isn't greyed out). The red underlining only appears at the first OVER in both cases.

Thanks in advance,
Michiel

Answer (score 3):

Pass the complete expression to `round()` including the `OVER` clause. The `OVER` clause and the window function all belong together.

```
...
round(avg(ratings.averagerating) OVER (PARTITION BY titletype))
...
```

And analog for the `cast()`.

Comment: @MichielV: [Edit] your question and include a [example], i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statements on the tables, sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. No images! Also tag the version of MySQL you are using.